# What is the best method to delete sub stores from Magento?

Tags: multistore, store-view, sales-order, delete

So we have a Magento setup with 1 main store and 48 sub stores. For a multitude of reasons we now want to reverse a lot of work quickly and essentially delete these 48 sub stores systematically. We want to delete all of the websites, store names and website views.

I realise that you can delete each sub store simply from the admin area on below page:

System > Manage Stores

Then select the website, store name or website view you want to delete.

Click delete and hey presto it's gone.

BUT we want to preserve the sales data and customer data.

Is this feasible or a distant pipe dream? If we have to delete the sales data and then re-upload it manually to our main store we can do this, but trying to avoid the manual admin as it will be 10-20 hours work to add the 500+ sub store orders back in to our main store. Any input or ideas would be greatly welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: No progress on this really, other than establishing you can view each stores sales data from the Magento admin dashboard, so you can quickly see which stores have few and which have high sales. We have begun manually deleting each store and are manually re-inputting the sales to our main store that will be stand alone after the 48 sub stores have been deleted manually. Pretty tedious work, but it looks like it will work eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so because there is no other articles on this online in any forum really we just dove in and started deleting sub stores, websites, websites etc. So all content, the products, categories etc. We had backups in place, so no real risk other than temporary downtime of 1 sub store etc.... Anyway, long and short of it is that the sales data and customer data is not deleted as their stored in DB tables that are not touched by the delete function. So the customer_ and sales_ tables are not affected. I hope this helps somebody else in the future who wants to delete stores. We've managed to clear a large amount of disk space and "should" see positive SEO results in a few weeks/months time starting to take shape.